# Rollup throws an error with the argument flag when using a custom config

Tags: rollupjs

I'm trying to use a custom config file

`rollup --environment NODE_ENV:dev -c rollup.d3.config.js`

Rollup successfully passes the argument into the config file.

But it throws a warning in the command line:

```
(!) You have passed an unrecognized option
Unknown input option: options. Allowed options: acorn, acornInjectPlugins, cache, context, entry, experimentalCodeSplitting, experimentalDynamicImport, experimentalPreserveModules, external, input, moduleContext, onwarn, perf, plugins, preferConst, preserveSymlinks, treeshake, watch
```

Is this the expected behavior? Am I writing the command the wrong way somehow? Whether I put the -c or --environment first, the same error throws.

Comment: Works fine for me with rollup version 0.59.1, can you post your config file?

Answer (score 0):

Rollup is expecting one of the options mentioned in "Allowed options" but based on the error, it looks as if you're adding a property called `options`, which rollup doesn't know what to do with.

If you have a variable called `options` whose contents you would like to merge with the rest of the configuration, you could use `Object.assign`:

```
const rollupConfig = {
  // ...
}

const options = {
  // ...
}

export default [Object.assign(rollupConfig, options)]
```